# Can we ask for recommendations for E-books on this website?

Tags: discussion

Is asking for recommendations for E-books relevant to this website? for instance, asking for recommendation about a new complete series of E-book(s) for learning C++ programming language.

Comment: You could ask it on the chat site, but unfortunately it seems to be quite dead these days: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12058/the-appendix Perhaps one of the stack overflow chat sites would be a good place to ask (e.g. for C++ https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, sorry. This site is really focused on the writing, editing, production, and publication of ebooks. Content-based recommendations are off-topic and highly subjective, which doesn't tend to work well in our Q&A format.